# if $A \subset X$ is compact then $d(x,A) = d(x,a)$ for some $a$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X$ be equipped with the metric $d$. If  a nonempty subset $A \subset X$ is compact, then $d(x,A ) = d(x,a)$ for some $a \in A$.

My attempt:

$$d(x,A ) : = \inf\{d(x,a)\ | \  a \in A\}$$.

$$d : X \times A \to \mathbb{R}$$.

Now, all I need to show is that if $A$ is compact, it's image under $d$ is closed  **(1)**

+

infimum of closed sets are contained in closet sets (in $\mathbb{R}$).  **(2)**

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Some variant of this question seems to arise every few days. I guess various syllabi must exhibit convergent evolution?

Comment: Show that $x \mapsto d(x,A)$ is Lipschitz continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that in a metric space:

- The image of a compact set under a continuous map is compact.
- A compact set is closed.

Instead of the map you consider it is better to consider:

$f_x: X \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f_x(a)= d(x,a)$

or also just defined on $A$ but the former feels a bit more natural.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: a real-valued continuous function on a compact set attains its infimum.

Answer (score 2):

Find some $(a_{n})$ such that $a_{n}\in A$ and $d(x,a_{n})\rightarrow d(x,A)$. Since $A$ is also sequentially compact, there exists some convergent subsequence $(a_{n_{k}})$ with limit point $a\in A$, so $d(x,a)=d(x,A)$.